# Python How to get the value of one specific point of derivative?

Tags: python, sympy, lambdify

```
from sympy import *
x = Symbol('x')
y = x ** 2
dx = diff(y, x)
```

This code can get the derivative of y.
It's easy `dx = 2 * x`

Now I want to get the value of `dx` for `x = 2`.

Clearly, `dx = 2 * 2 = 4` when `x = 2`

But how can I realize this with python codes?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Just `dx.subs(x, 2)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably the most versatile way is to `lambdify`:

`sympy.lambdify` creates and returns a function that you can assign to a name, and call, like any other python callable.

```
from sympy import *

x = Symbol('x')
y = x**2
dx = diff(y, x)
print(dx, dx.subs(x, 2))  # this substitutes 2 for x as suggested by @BugKiller in the comments

ddx = lambdify(x, dx)     # this creates a function that you can call
print(ddx(2))
```

Answer (score 2):

According to SymPy's [documentation](http://www.cfm.brown.edu/people/dobrush/am33/SymPy/index.html#evalf) you have to *evaluate* the value of the function after *substituting* `x` with the desired value:

```
>>> dx.evalf(subs={x: 2})
4.00000000000000
```

or

```
>>> dx.evalf(2, subs={x: 2})
4.0
```

to limit the output to two digits.